# ImportERROR: from . import postgresql, mysql, sqlite, mssql, oracle # pragma: no cover ImportError: cannot import name 'mysql'

Tags: python, alembic

I'm trying to use flask application on my web.

I've installed Flask, Flask-Session, psycopg2-binary, and SQLAlchemy

After that I try a simple code from flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

The output expected is link to open my flask application,
but after do 'flask run' on my terminal, I get this errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 781, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 700, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1209, in parse_args
    echo(ctx.get_help(), color=ctx.color)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 570, in get_help
    return self.command.get_help(self)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 975, in get_help
    self.format_help(ctx, formatter)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1003, in format_help
    self.format_options(ctx, formatter)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in format_options
    self.format_commands(ctx, formatter)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1184, in format_commands
    for subcommand in self.list_commands(ctx):
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 549, in list_commands
    self._load_plugin_commands()
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 523, in _load_plugin_commands
    self.add_command(ep.load(), ep.name)
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2446, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2452, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from alembic import __version__ as __alembic_version__
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/alembic/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import context  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/alembic/context.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .runtime.environment import EnvironmentContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .migration import MigrationContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .. import ddl, util
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/alembic/ddl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import postgresql, mysql, sqlite, mssql, oracle  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: cannot import name 'mysql'
```

Comment: It appears Flask is picking the (incomplete) alembic package from a different place than it should be, assuming you installed SQLAlchemy yourself. Could you check whether `/home/xenoveals/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic` exists?

Comment: ah solved. thanks to this comment.. I try to pip3 install alembic and now it's fine. Thanks"

Answer (score -1):

You should call `app.run()` at the end. Or better

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can change the `port` if you want to like this `app.run(port=5000)`